# Increasing speed of IMAP bulk message deletion in python

Tags: python, iteration, imaplib

The goal is to remove bunch of email messages using imaplib. Email folder receives approximately 300k new messages a month. Only messages that are older than 1 month should be deleted. If executing this script it will delete old messages, but deletion takes a lot of time and simple for iteration does not look effective. It takes several hours.
By trying to increase speed with multiprocessing gives error.

What can you advise to improve the speed of deleting big amount of messages?

```
import sys
import datetime
from imaplib import IMAP4

# get the date a month from the current
monthbefore = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(365/12)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")

m = IMAP4('mail.domain.com')
m.login('user@domain.com', 'password')

# shows how many messages in selected folder
print m.select('Folder')
typ, data = m.select('Folder')

# find old messages
typ, data = m.search(None, '(BEFORE %s)' % (monthbefore))

# delete them
print "Will be removed:\t", data[0].split()[-1],"messages"
for num in data[0].split():
  m.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
  sys.stderr.write('\rRemoving message:\t %s' % num)

# now expunge marked for deletion messages, close connection and exit
print "\nGet ready for expunge"
m.expunge()
print "Expunged! Quiting."
m.close()
m.logout()
```

**Update:** Rewrited part of a code, here is a 1000 times faster working variant (my server supports store command to more than 1000 messages at a time):

```
    def chunks(l, n):
        # yields successive n-sized chunks from l.
        for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
            yield l[i:i+n]

    mcount = data[0].split()[-1]
    print "Will be removed", mcount, "messages"
    for i in list(chunks(data[0].split(), 1000)):
        m.store(",".join(i), '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
        sys.stderr.write('\rdone {0:.2f}%'.format((int(i[-1])/int(mcount)*100)))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that you're calling STORE for each message. Each one of those round trips to the server takes time and when you're doing lots of deletions this really adds up.

To avoid all those calls to STORE trying calling it with multiple message ids. You can either pass a comma separate listed (e.g. `"1,2,3,4"`), ranges of message ids (e.g. `"1:10"`) or a combination of both (e.g. `"1,2,5,1:10"`). Note that most servers seem to have a limit on the number of message ids allowed per call so you'll probably still need to chunk the ids into blocks (of say 200 messages) and call STORE multiple times. This will still be much, much faster than calling STORE per message.

For further reference, see the [STORE Command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.6) section of RFC 3501. It shows an example of a STORE command taking a range of message ids.

Comment: Somewhat tangential to this but related: you may want to consider using IMAPClient for this job instead of imaplib. It takes care of a lot of the messy details of parsing IMAP responses for you. For example, search() gives a list of integer ids instead of a string which you need to split. http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/

Comment: Thanks, your hint worked like a charm. Rewrited my script using it.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a certain amount of time to do the deletion and if you do them one at a time, it's going to take a long, long time. The overhead of the `for` loop is minuscule compared to the amount of time you're spending waiting for the server to do its thing. Several hours is not out of line, nor does it strike me as particularly problematic; you *have* several hours, I am sure.  If you don't, just start sooner.

Still, if it's a problem, you're on the right track with threading or multiprocessing. I don't know what you mean by "gives error"; a little more specificity might be nice before giving up on that approach. If you mean your server won't allow multiple simultaneous logins, that can probably be configured on your IMAP server. (I use CommuniGate Pro to handle e-mail for my domain and it allows this.)

Another approach would be to run the deletion script once a day or even once an hour so the time cost is spread out over the month. You might also try POP3 instead of IMAP to see if it's any faster for this application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's little you can do. In IMAP, flagging a message as deleted is pretty quick; it's the `expunge` that's the killer.

And you can't do that in multiprocessing, because only one thread is allowed to lock the mailbox to do the physical expunging.

If you tried to run a multiprocessing delete - on most servers I believe you actually *could* - you'd speed up dramatically a process that's already very quick. But then the single thread running `expunge` would need to lock for a long time; depending on the server, you might even be unable to login during this "dead time". Some other servers (I think Icewarp's Merak) will allow normal operations during an expunge (you're simply not allowed to run a *second* expunge until the first has finished).

**UPDATE**

I have done a bit of experimenting. I found that to have different connections through `imaplib`, the login itself has to be moved into a `Thread`.

So I set up the app like this:

- the main app logs in and retrieves the list of messages to be deleted
- divides the messages in N chunks
- starts N threads that run the login
- all threads wait for a small time to let every thread complete the login (so that message indexes are the same through all connections); I really should have employed synchronization here
- each thread starts deleting its assigned portion of the messages, then logs out
- when all the threads have finished, the main app continues and purges the mailbox

I noticed a performance increase with N=2 which increased at N=3. Then no increase for N=4, i.e., each thread in a set of four took the same time to delete 25 messages than a thread in a set of three employed to delete 33 messages. Again no increase for N from 5 up to 7. At N=8 performance started decreasing; at ten the server stopped accepting connections.

In my best scenario I estimate the deletion time to have been around 40% of nominal with three threads running; I'm not sure whether this justifies the trouble.

But these values are in all probability strongly dependent on server architecture, and hardware (how many processors and cores, how much memory) as well as maximum number of concurrent connections allowed. So you might take more advantage from a multithreaded approach.

I also ran some tests server side. Since most IMAP servers ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers ) store their data in a variant of Maildir format, one file for message, and the timestamp of the message is embedded in the file name, I experimented with a program to delete any files containing an older timestamp. This method has the disadvantage of requiring the user to be logged off, but it is very fast.

It would also be possible, and I think it would not really interfere with user operations, to mark files as "to be deleted" (adding 'T' to the info file suffix) so all that remains is to issue an expunge command to make the server physically kill the files and recalculate immediately the quotas, if any.

Running periodically such a program would accomplish message expiration more efficiently, if access to the server can be obtained.

Comment: Actually expunge takes a lot less time then iteration over 700k emails. Does multiprocessing using imaplib.store command opens another connection to server?

Comment: Added some results from last night.

Comment: Thank you, i will try with 3 threads as my mail server accepts 3 simultaneous connections but is there any way to see the progress?

Comment: Yes, you print a dot for each kill; they'll overlap on stdout and you can count them. I passed each thread the start and end ID to delete; **make sure** each thread has had time to login before it starts deleting, otherwise (if a thread starts deleting before the others have logged in) the new threads will "see" different IDs, and delete the wrong messages. Perhaps it'd be best if each thread repeated the date query, and deleted the IDs *from the list thus obtained* (hence valid) that fall within the assigned bounds. Some messages that should have been deleted might not be, but not vice versa.

Comment: >the new threads will "see" different IDs. Will not until expunge.

Comment: Uhm. What you say makes LOTS of sense. I had noticed IDs changing while experimenting, but maybe that was because an expunge was under way - I had not yet organized my threads properly.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing one big chunk at it works for me, the email server breaks it down for itself. Tailor this as you wish for non Gmail IMAP servers:

```
#!/bin/python

import datetime
import imaplib

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")  # server to connect to
m.login('gmail@your_gmail.com', 'your_password')

print m.select('[Gmail]/All Mail')  
before_date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(365)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")  # date string, 04-Jan-2013
typ, data = m.search(None, '(BEFORE {0})'.format(before_date))  

if data != ['']:  # messages exist
    no_msgs = data[0].split()[-1]  # last msg id in the list
    print "To be removed:\t", no_msgs, "messages found with date before", before_date
    m.store("1:{0}".format(no_msgs), '+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')  # move to trash, can also set Delete Flag here instead
    print "Deleted {0} messages. Closing connection & logging out.".format(no_msgs)
else:
    print "Nothing to remove."

#This block empties trash, Gmail auto purges trash after 30 days anyways.
print("Emptying Trash & Expunge...")
m.select('[Gmail]/Trash')  # select all trash
m.store("1:*", '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')  #Flag all Trash as Deleted
m.expunge()  # not need if auto-expunge enabled in Gmail

m.close()
m.logout()
```